# pyflakes bug when saving python scripts in vim

Tags: python, vim, macvim, pyflakes

I am encountering an annoying problem with MacVim using pyflakes as I am programming with python in my terminal on OS X. Basically when I attempt to exit and save my script (Shift+zz) I get a bunch of errors popping up and labeled as 'EE' in my vim, (see below). At this point anything I type in MacVim just comes up as the symbols you see on line 42, i.e. the only option I have is to exit by ctrl+z! Im not sure why these are errors because my script runs fine, so its not like the import statements are not recognised! Also these 'EEs' only come up if I'm saving my file after I make changes. If I open my file again after the errors come up and then save and exit, voila - I exit nicely without problems. What could this be due to?

[image]

Comment: I suppose those `EE`s are signs added by some syntax-checking script. What plugins do you use?

Comment: I have installed MacVim, which I think changes the nature of the original vim, although the vim I am using is still the one contained in `/usr/bin/vim`. Apart from MacVim (which I installed using macports i believe, I have made no changes to my vim. Perhaps MacVim are a set of plugins that changed it?

Comment: No, MacVim doesn't change anything to the default Vim. Since you have installed it, why don't you use it in the terminal too?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear - (I'm a bit confused) I believe I am using MacVim from the terminal. Right now what you see above is when I do `vim test.py` the only reason I say I use MacVim is because my vim environment changed appearance when I installed MacVim, even when I just run vim. Therefore I assumed that the MacVim installation somehow changed the vim I originally had.